# Apple Push Notification Service which ios version it is supported from?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

I m not sure where to find which ios Version starts supporting Apple Push Notification Service? Or it does not matter ?

Comment: Wiki? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it’s worth, the various related symbols like `UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert` appeared in iOS 3. In other words, the support is so old it does not really matter today.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple Push Notification Service is a service created by Apple Inc. that was launched together with iOS 3.0

[Refer Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Please refer this link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service

Answer (score 0):

There are different versions for different use cases. For example if you want a custom notification, you should use notification extensions.

### - **UNNotificationContentExtension**

- iOS 10.0+

### - **UNNotificationServiceExtension**

- iOS 10.0+
- macOS 10.14+

If you want to have a simple default notification, all you need is a simple implementation in code without importing anything.

### - **Apple Push Notification Service (aka 'APS' and 'APNS')**

- iOS 3.0+